# I am new to Reactive Programming trying UPSERT operation using Mono and concat with existed value in repository

Tags: spring-boot, rest, microservices, reactive-programming, java-11

Here, In PUT method  if it is empty invoking POST using REST API if not request payload going to save in repository

I need to save like append the existed field value with updated one. please if you any idea on this help me out

public Mono updateEmployee(int id,Employee emp){

return repo.existsById(id)

.switchIfEmpty(service.create(emp))

.flatMap(repo.save(emp);
}